# Provisioning profiles and iOS Today Extension

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I created a today extension and when I go to submit to the app store though Xcode 6 and I get this error, does anyone know how I can fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this same error yesterday. I solved it by going in to member center and creating a **distribution** provisioning profile for my Today Extension. The new distribution provisioning profile needs to have the App ID for your Today Extension.